# PL/SQL arabic displayed as?

Tags: sql, plsql, arabic, plsqldeveloper

When I query for data that have arabic text in PL/SQL Developer, It is showed as question marks (????).

I am sure the data is correctly stored in DB because it shows on website properly, also on the server.

So I think it is a problem related to my PL/SQL Developer (v8.0.4.1514).

- Is there any way to change how PL/SQL Developer shows/encodes arabic text?
- How to check in what format/encoding the arabic text is stored?

My question might be missing some details, So Just ask me and also keep in mind that I am very beginner in PL/SQL and in SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: can you tell what is the value of SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE

Comment: Tell me how to find this value and I will provide it

Comment: SELECT VALUE as Language FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_LANGUAGE';

Comment: try ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'ARABIC'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution (which might also work with other languages that shows as '`????`')

I changed the `NLS_LANG` in registry to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

(I found 3 `NLS_LANG`'s in registry, check with each one or just change them all like I did.)

then restarted PL/SQL developer, test a query and arabic text is showing normally.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

can you `SET NLS_LANGUAGE` to Arabic by `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'ARABIC'`

it could be the solution, if not can you provide more information about O/S and it's version, ... etc

Comment: After doing so and executing a query it shows an error message (??? ??? ????) My OS is Win7 64 Pro. Keep in mind that the result have english and arabic text.

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple instance of oracle installed so you must set default enconding for all of them. Just follow this instructions:

1. Open reg edit and go to  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle`. There is one or more keys related to each instance:

[image]

2. For **each** of this keys right click and create a string value named `NLS_LANG` if not already there:

[image]

3. Then set it's value to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` and done just refresh your query in PL/SQL.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in registery find `NLS_LANG` and change its value from `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`
it works fine for me for persian characters.